# vector<T>::swap and temporary object

Tags: c++, vector, swap, temporary-objects

Code goes below:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1(5,1);
    v1.swap(vector<int> ());  //try to swap v1 with a temporary vector object
}
```

The code above cannot compile, error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::swap(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
```

But, if I change the code to something like this, it can compile:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v1(5,1);
    vector<int> ().swap(v1);
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `vector<int>()` is an [**rvalue**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) (a temporary, roughly speaking), and you cannot bind a non-`const` reference to an rvalue.  So in this case, you cannot pass it to a function taking a non-`const` reference.

However, it's perfectly fine to invoke member functions on temporaries, which is why your second example compiles.

Comment: Could you plz offer more info on "`vector<int>()` is an rvalue"? `rvalue` should appear on the right side of `=`, right?

Comment: @Alcott: It's more general than that.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science).

Comment: I found this article very helpful in understanding rvalues: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

Answer (score 7):

The call `v1.swap(std::vector<int>())` tries to bind a temporary (i.e. `std::vector<int>()`) to a non-const reference. This is illegal and fails. On the other hand, using `std::vector<int>().swap(v1)` calls a non-const function on the [non-const] temporary which is allowed.

In C++2011 I would have thought that the declaration would be changed to `std::vector<T>::swap(T&&)` and it would thus become OK to use `swap()` with temporaries (but, obviously, still not with `const` objects). As GMan pointed out this isn't the case.